# Create css for justified tabs in Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am creating justified tabs using Bootstrap 3 responsive.
   For each tab I want the map image as shown in attached image. Not able to view the map image.

[image]

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/monicaRegal/jt4r946a/)

HTML:

```
<div role="tabpanel">

    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="America"><span>The Americas</span></a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Europe</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Asia/Pacific</a></li>
    </ul>

    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">The Americas content</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile" id="Europe">Europe content</div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings" id="Asia">Asia/Pacific content</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a {
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border-top:0!important;
    border-bottom:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#0a3c91;
    border-radius:0;
    color:#fff!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#America:active {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAmericaActive.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#America {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAmerica.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#Europe:active {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapEuropeActive.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#Europe {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapEurope.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#Asia:active {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAsiaActive.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#Asia {
    background:url(http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAsia.png) no-repeat center;
    border-bottom:4px solid #093!important;
    border-top:0;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
    color:#000!important;
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Okay, is this something you're trying to rebuild from an existing app, or are you simply trying to build another website's functionality without actually doing much of your own work? This could likely be done with a small bit of jquery to switch the images depending on what tab is clicked....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should get you close to what you want. It'll still require you to format a couple of pieces like the hover over effects, but the overall structure is there for you.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/1dgvmuy1/2/)

One major problem I noticed in you're code was the usage of `:active` on the links. The `:active` pseudo class is only used to define styling when a link is clicked. Here you actually want something to have styling based on a class instead.

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#America:active
```

Instead of that you should be doing:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a#America
```

In the HTML, I modified the way you were trying to do it. I've added to separate tags for the map and the map text. This makes it easier to style the line that you want to separate the two areas. Once I did this, I made some tweaks to your CSS.

```
<div style="height: 100px">
    <!--Space element just to get it off the panel splitter.-->
</div>
<div role="tabpanel">
  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" role="tablist">
      <li role="presentation" class="active">
          <a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <span class="map" id="America">&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="mapText">The Americas</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <span class="map" id="Europe">&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="mapText">Europe</span>
          </a>
      </li>
      <li role="presentation">
          <a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
              <span class="map" id="Asia">&nbsp;</span>
              <span class="mapText">Asia/Pacific</span>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">The Americas content</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile" id="Europe">Europe content</div>
      <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings" id="Asia">Asia/Pacific content</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a {
    border: none !important;
    border-radius:0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a:hover {
    border: none;
    border-radius:0;
    background-color: inherit !important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a > .mapText {
    border: none;
    border-top:4px solid #FFF!important;
    display: block;
    background-color:#0a3c91;
    color:#fff;
    padding: 20px 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a > .mapText {
    border-top:4px solid #093!important;
    background-color: #FFF;
    color: #000;    
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a > .map {
    border: none;
    height: 90px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    display: block;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a {
    border-right:1px solid #fff;
    background-color:#fff;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a > #America {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAmericaActive.png') no-repeat center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a > #America {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAmerica.png') no-repeat center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a > #Europe {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapEuropeActive.png') no-repeat center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a > #Europe {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapEurope.png') no-repeat center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li.active > a > #Asia {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAsiaActive.png') no-repeat center;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified > li > a > #Asia {
    background:url('http://bestindiatravel.net/Monica/mapAsia.png') no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, it worked :) 
Just need to do few tweaks in css for mobile resolution as blue bar is not expanding 100%.

Its leaving extra space on right hand side.

Comment: @MonicaMandal: Good to hear it's working. I didn't test any mobile browsers, but I did test the responsive layout. I do know JSFiddle tricked me into thinking the same thing when I was working on it. There's a small gap in JSFiddle on the right side of the result pane, but that's not part of the output. Not sure if that's what you're seeing, but might save you a couple minutes of debugging if it is.